# autodesk eagle 9.6.2 and appropriate gerber files for one-sided printed circuit board

Tags: gerber

I am designing a one-sided printed circuit board using Autodesk Eagle 9.6.2.   In this  design I put the components on the top of the board and the traces on the bottom of the board.  All the components are through hole (TH). I am  unsure about what Gerber files are needed or should be used for the manufacturing part. What Gerber files are needed in this case ?  Are there Gerber files that are irrelevant in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single sided bare PCB made in a professional proto shop you would want:

1. top silk screen (optional, but useful)
2. bottom copper
3. bottom solder mask (optional, but very useful)
4. board outline
5. drill file for non-PTHs only (see below)

**6. top copper (see below)

**7. drill file for PTH (see below)

If you don't have any silk screen on the bottom you can leave that one out or send it with nothing on it.

That's three or four fewer than you'd have with a 2-layer board (top solder mask, top copper, bottom silk screen) and either all holes would be PTH or there might be two drill files, one for NPTH and one for PTH.

There's a bit of a twist with proto houses that use  a 2-layer PTH work flow to make single layer boards in that they don't like copper to get too close to the NPTH edges. They can probably modify your gerber file silently (and without extra charge) to fix that, and I'd give that a try before mucking with it myself. The layout rules will be quite different for a good single-sided design anyway- pads for THT parts should be quite a bit larger, particularly if the components have much mass to them. Or they could make the board with pads on both sides and all (or most) holes PTH but you would then have to supply the top copper file (which would consist of only pads). Depending on *why* you are prototyping the single-sided board you might pick one or the other.

Note also that, unlike the old days with single-sided boards, it's now universally conventional to create boards looking down from the top through the board, so text on the bottom layer (perhaps in the copper on your board) will appear mirrored. If you're etching the board yourself you don't need to follow that convention, but it's not a bad idea to get used to it. (musing- I wonder if we could even have bought mirrored Letraset in the old days). You'll still find some footprints for components that have been unchanged over decades in particular (relays come to mind) documented in the opposite way (view from the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

If you are having the board made by a prototype PCB shop, they will almost certainly want to make it double-sided, so will want top and bottom copper, top and bottom solder mask and top silkscreen.

If you are making it yourself, all you really need is the bottom copper layer.

In either case, you also require a drill file.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  so it's about  what the requirements are for the pcb  manufacturer ?  I thought it was just about following the circuit theory and then directing  the software setup according to the circuit needs.  I am curious as to why a top copper layer in my case ?  my traces are on the bottom.  what would be the purpose of a copper layer on the top also ?

Comment: A board shop will start with a PC board with copper on both sides, and etch away the copper you don't want.  A normal board will have pads around the holes on both sides, and the finished board will have copper plating in the holes, connecting the pads on both sides.  If you want copper on one side only, and no plating in the holes, this will upset their normal processing, and probably won't save any money.

Comment: Picked JLCPCB as a random example of a manufacturer, and their https://jlcpcb.com/quote/pcbOrderFaq/PCB%20Layer page contains ``It is the copper layer for your PCB, for example, if there is one copper layer only, then it is 1 layer`` and ``Note: For 1 layer PCB, there will be one side with solder mask only, if you want to cover it with solder mask for 2 sides, you may need to order it as 2 layers.`` I.e. appears some manufacturers support a single sided PCB.